# Unsupported Media Type when updating values using the TeamCity REST API

Tags: powershell, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have a Powershell script that I use to synchonize various projects parameters.  The relevant code I use to update a project parameter is:

```
$propName = "ReleaseNumber"
$propValue = "10.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -method Put -uri "$server/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/$targetProject/parameters/$propName" -Body "$propValue"
```

After the upgrade to TeamCity 9.1, I started receiving the following error when using the script:

> *Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.*

What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, the `ContentType` sent by Powershell's `Invoke-RestMethod` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Prior to TeamCity 9.1, TeamCity didn't seem to care much about the `ContentType` for the project-related API calls, but with 9.1, and the [addition of both XML and JSON payloads](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-ProjectSettings), it looks like TeamCity is being more picky about content types. So, since your property values are just plain text, to resolve the problem specify `text/plain` as the `ContentType`, like so:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -contentType "text/plain" -method Put -uri "$server/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/$targetProject/parameters/$propName" -body "$propValue"
```