# Using the Cogos Analytics REST API from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rest, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

Using Cognos Analytics 11.2.4
Trying to write a PowerShell script to administer Cognos Analytics through the Cognos Analytics REST API.  My first attempt is to create a new session (login).  I'm getting nowhere so far.

Following documentation and help found at:
[IBM Cognos Analytics REST API](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.2.0?topic=apis-rest-api) (and related)
https://MyServerName:9300/api/api-docs/
[PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.4)
[Unsupported Media Type when updating values using the TeamCity REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160795/unsupported-media-type-when-updating-values-using-the-teamcity-rest-api)

Whenever I try this I get an error:
`Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.`

The local API documentation on the server does not include 415 as a possible response.  (...which wouldn't help anyway because the documentation doesn't include any likely causation with the error responses that are in the docs.)

How can I get past this?  I could really use a nudge in the right direction.

Here is the code I have tried.  Previous attempts are included and commented out.

```
#  docs at
#  http://<cognos_analytics_server>:<port>/api/api-docs

$serverName = "<cognos_analytics_server>"
$port = "<port>"
$userNamespace = "<external_directory_namespace>"
$userName = Read-Host "User Name:  "

$pwd = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd)
$userPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)
# then free up the unmanged memory afterwards
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)

#  Attempt 1
#$p = @()
#$p += @{
#      name = "CAMNamespace"
#      value = $userNamespace
#    }
#$p += @{
#      name = "CAMUsername"
#      value = $userName
#    }
#$p += @{
#      name = "CAMPassword"
#      value = $userPassword
#    }
#
#$body = @{
#  parameters = $p
#}

#  Attempt 2
#$body = '{
#  "parameters": [
#    {
#      "name": "CAMNamespace",
#      "value": "' + $userNamespace + '"
#    },
#    {
#      "name": "CAMUsername",
#      "value": "' + $userName + '"
#    },
#    {
#      "name": "CAMPassword",
#      "value": "' + $userPassword + '"
#    }
#  ]
#}'

#  Attempt 3
#$body = '{"parameters": [{"name": "CAMNamespace","value": "' + $userNamespace + '"},{"name": "CAMUsername","value": "' + $userName + '"},{"name": "CAMPassword","value": "' + $userPassword + '"}]}'

#  Attempt 4
#$body = "{`"parameters`": [{`"name`": `"CAMNamespace`",`"value`": `"$userNamespace`"},{`"name`": `"CAMUsername`",`"value`": `"$userName`"},{`"name`": `"CAMPassword`",`"value`": `"$userPassword`"}]}"

#  Attempt 5
$body = "{
  `"parameters`": [
    {
      `"name`": `"CAMNamespace`",
      `"value`": `"$userNamespace`"
    },
    {
      `"name`": `"CAMUsername`",
      `"value`": `"$userName`"
    },
    {
      `"name`": `"CAMPassword`",
      `"value`": `"$userPassword`"
    }
  ]
}"


$uri = "$protocol`://$serverName`:$port/api/v1/session"

#  Attempt 1
#Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Body $body

#  Further attempts
Invoke-RestMethod -contentType "text/plain" -Uri $uri -Method Put -Body $body
```

Comment: As a shot to nothing, you could try```-ContentType “application/json”```. Also, your code to generate the body might be cleaner if you build a hashtable / pscustomobject structure and then use ```ConvertTo-Json``` rather than hand-crank the json yourself - you’ll get better syntax highlighting in your IDE, and you’ll be less likely to have typos like unclosed / unmatched quotes and brace, etc…

Comment: @mclayton Care to make that an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Swagger documentation at https://www.ibm.com/docs/swagger/?configuration=SSEP7J_12.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ca_api.doc/swagger_ca.json#/session/create_update_session gives a little bit more of a clue about how to make a correct request:

[image]

If you change your code to:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $uri -Method Put -Body $body
```

it might get you past the "Unsupported Media" error.

@DanielWagemann's link to the documentation at https://developer.ibm.com/apis/catalog/cognosanalytics--cognos-analytics-rest-api/api/API--cognosanalytics--cognos-analytics#create_update_session also includes a `curl` example that you can use to model your `Invoke-RestMethod` calls:

```
curl --request PUT \
  --url REPLACE_ENDPOINT_VARIABLE/api/v1/session \
  --header 'IBM-BA-Authorization: REPLACE_THIS_VALUE' \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data REPLACE_REQUEST_BODY
```

See `--header 'content-type: application/json'` above which basically suggests using `-ContentType "application/json"` for `Invoke-RestMethod` as well...

Comment: I saw that after reading your comment.  This is my first time using the CA REST API, using Swagger, etc.  Thank you for getting me over this speed bump.

Answer (score 0):

The following link might be helpful https://developer.ibm.com/apis/catalog/cognosanalytics--cognos-analytics-rest-api/Introduction

Comment: That's the same information found at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.2.0?topic=apis-rest-api

Comment: I find the workable examples in that link more helpful.  It also It also calls out the Context Type.  Personal preference I guess.